# calculate/check date of birth is less than 110 years old in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, validation, date

I have a date array like this:

```
var dateArray = ["1965-12-29", "1902-11-04", "1933-10-21", "1983-10-16"];
```

What I would like to do is check/calculate each date of birth element to see if age is less than 110 years old based on year only. If age is greater than 110 years (also based on year only), then I would like to have this element remove/deleted from dateArray.

Basically, What I am trying to do is convert the following SQL code in JavaScript:

```
FROM TABLE X
WHERE TO_CHAR(DOB, 'YYYY') > (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2014/09/30', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'YYYY') - 110)
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: loop through the array, create a date object, do a comparison.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Can you please help with the comparison ? thanks ... New to JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `.getFullYear()` method of Date type](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp):

```
for(var i=0;i<dateArray.length;i++)
{
   var now = new Date();// or specify any date you want with new Date("2014/10/15");
   var birth = new Date(dateArray[i]);
   var age = now.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear();
   //then use the age var and test if it's bigger than 110
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var dateArray = ["1965-12-29", "1902-11-04", "1933-10-21", "1983-10-16"];
dateArray = removeOldPeople(dateArray);

function removeOldPeople(dateArray){ 
    //looping backwards because I delete items from array in loop
    for(var i = dateArray.length -1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
      var dateString = dateArray[i].split("-");
      var year = dateString[0];
      var month = parseInt(dateString[1])-1;
      var day = dateString[2];
      var age = calculateAge(day, month, year);
        if(age >= 110) {
            dateArray =  dateArray.splice(i);
        }
    }
}

function calculateAge(birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear){
  todayDate = new Date();
  todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
  todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth();
  todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
  age = todayYear - birthYear; 

  if (todayMonth < birthMonth - 1){
    age--;
  }

  if (birthMonth - 1 == todayMonth && todayDay < birthDay){
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```

Comment: Hazaart ...I forgot to mention, that a parameter date value will be passed in such as '2014/09/30', and based on that year (for example, 2014), everything should be calculated. thanks for the help.